# Watson studio supports jupyter datatables?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, watson-studio

I'm trying to execute jupyter_datatables in Watson studio notebook, but it's showing me an error.
Can you help me? Do you know Watson studio supports Jupiter data tables?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Jupyter Datatables](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-datatables/) is a notebook extension. Users cannot install and enable arbitrary notebook extensions in Watson Studio on Cloud. So I don't think you'll get this to work.